# SQLITE create table with FOREIGN key and Composite key

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am new in Android sqlite database, so i am not able to figure out what is the right syntax for writing this create statement with primary key and foreign key. below i am going to past my column names and create table statement. I am hoping that someone guide me what i am doing wrong in this.

```
//table names
public static final String TABLE_configuracao_situacao = "configuracao_situacao";
public static final String TABLE_situacao = "situacao";

//column names for Situation table
public static final String KEY_idSituacao = "id_situacao";
public static final String KEY_descicao = "descricao";
public static final String KEY_padrao = "padrao";
public static final String KEY_button = "button";

//column names for configuracao_situacao table
public static final String KEY_situacao = "situacao";
public static final String KEY_configuracao = "configuracao";
public static final String KEY_minimo = "minimo";
public static final String KEY_maximo = "maximo";
public static final String KEY_acaoMin = "acao_min";
public static final String KEY_acaoMax = "acao_max";
public static final String KEY_dataCriacao = "data_criacao";

//Table created statement for situation
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SITUACAO =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_situacao 
        + "("   +   KEY_idSituacao  + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                +   KEY_descicao    + " string , "
                +   KEY_padrao      + " string, "
                +   KEY_button      + " integer "
        + ");";

//Table created statement configuracao_situacao
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_Table_CONFIGSITUACAO =
        "CREATE TABLE " +   TABLE_configuracao_situacao
        + "("   +   KEY_situacao        + " integer primary key, "
                +   KEY_configuracao    + " integer primary key, "
                +   KEY_minimo          + " text, "
                +   KEY_maximo          + " text, "
                +   KEY_acaoMin         + " text, "
                +   KEY_acaoMax         + " text, "
                +   KEY_dataCriacao     + " DATETIME, "
                "FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_situacao + " ) REFERENCES " +  TABLE_situacao + "(" + KEY_idSituacao + ")"
        + ");";
```

the problem is in configuracao_situacao create statement, while making foregin key. can someone tell me how can i define the key here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks ok, could you post the error msg you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

you have used wrong data type 
Check Below code you will get reference

```
//Table created statement for situation
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SITUACAO =
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_situacao 
    + "("   +   KEY_idSituacao  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +   KEY_descicao    + " TEXT, "
            +   KEY_padrao      + " TEXT, "
            +   KEY_button      + " INTEGER"
    + ");";
//Table created statement configuracao_situacao
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_Table_CONFIGSITUACAO =
    "CREATE TABLE " +   TABLE_configuracao_situacao
    + "("   +   KEY_situacao        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            +   KEY_configuracao    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            +   KEY_minimo          + " TEXT,"
            +   KEY_maximo          + " TEXT,"
            +   KEY_acaoMin         + " TEXT,"
            +   KEY_acaoMax         + " TEXT,"
            +   KEY_dataCriacao     + " TEXT,"
            "FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_situacao + " ) REFERENCES " +  TABLE_situacao + "(" + KEY_idSituacao + ")"
    + ");";
```

Comment: Hi Ando Masahashi, I am getting foreign key as nulls.Can you please look at it.These are my 2 tables Table 1 - final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists scannerValuess (id integer,partName text null,cost text null,foreign key(id) references scannerUserValuess(userid))"; Table 2 - final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_USER = "create table if not exists scannerUserValuess (userid integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null,mobile text not null,address text not null,date text not null)"; Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Naveen can you tell me your execution sequence means which statement are you executing first

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have extra comma after DATETIME:

+KEY_dataCriacao     + " DATETIME, "

And SQLite don't have type field DATETIME and string

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html